# iOS: Change Orientation only for few pop-up views

Tags: ios, device-orientation, uideviceorientation

I have an app which runs only in Landscape mode. All working well. But I have few pop-up views like Apptentative feedback view and Twitter Sheet view, works great when in portrait mode. So how can I change orientation forcefully when loading these pop-ups and back to landscape when these pop-up closes.

Answer (score 1):

You can't force an orientation change. You can only support changes in orientation. IE moving the device 90 degrees to the right.

Comment: can you give me some sample code. I want to allow user to go to Portrait mode when these pop-up views are loaded on other view even if user rotate device orientation shouldn't change

Comment: You can't force an orientation change. You can only write code to deal with it.